# "onPressed: () {}" doesn't work in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';



  void main() {
    runApp(const XylophoneApp());
  }

 class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
   const XylophoneApp({super.key});

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return const MaterialApp(
       home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: TextButton(onPressed: () {
              final player = Audiocache();
              player.play('note1.wav');

            },
              child: Text('Click Me'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
     );
  }
 }
```

when i click on run button it says "Error: Not a constant expression." and when i write a new onPressed on an another project its still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `const` modifier on `MaterialApp` will do the fix.

`const MaterialApp` -> `MaterialApp`.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. Can you explain to me why it did fix it?

Comment: `onPressed` function you provide to `TextButton` is not a valid `const`, so your `MaterialApp` can not be `const`.

Comment: 1. Function expressions are not constant expressions in Dart, so the onPressed function itself cannot be constant.
2. The player variable is an instance of the AudioCache class, which is created at runtime, and its play method has side effects (it plays a sound). This makes it a non-constant expression.